# Need personal music collection streaming solution

Tags: audio, apache-http-server, php, streaming, music-streaming

I used to use Opera and it's built in media server feature for some time and it both worked and looked really well. It's dead now and i'm in search of a decent audio streaming solution (Windows 8) to be able to stream my music collection via http to work or whatever..

I tried couple of PHP scripts but they all looked really awful, also, tried couple of solutions mentioned here at Superuser but i wasn't really satisfied..

I tried vibestreamer as well and while it looks really nice i'm not really into installing it as an application. I've set up an WAMP server which i intend to use in this purpose.

I'd be mostly satisfied with a way to browse my collection folders and pick the one i want to play, no playlists and various sorting features a la iTunes.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OwnCloud](http://www.owncloud.org/). It's a PHP application that supports media streaming through the web interface and works quite well.

Also for a LAN solution, take a look at [Plex media server](http://www.plexapp.com/).

Comment: I tried both, OwnCLoud sucked as it had buggy music player and i didn't really needed all other bells and whistles it offers. Plex was good but as i mentioned, i wouldn't want to have to install anything. It needs way too much time to index my media and it's not really portable solution (i would have to reinstall it every single time i reinstall my OS). I'd prefer a simple PHP script to do this for me.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about OwnClowd, the newest release works great at my house but I run it off a FreeNAS box. Have you looked at Google Music upload?

Comment: well, i have 160GB collection, i can't take all that to Google..

Comment: Gotcha, good luck in your search

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, forget this stuff, i just discovered MPD for Windows. Nothing can't beat this as far as i'm concerned.

http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Windows_Compatibility#Server

Comment: subsonic is the best i found. on linux, says it runs on windows also though.